# How disable auto login with sign with linkedin when trying to signin for second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linkedin-api

I'm using react-social-login library, when I click on sign with linkedin for first time it need to enter account credentials but second time I click it auto login.
I need to implement that every time button click it should need credentials or disable auto login on second time.
Please how can I do that?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?  If authentication is being performed by a 3rd party then the only information you have or need from that 3rd party is whether or not the user is authenticated.  *When* the user last authenticated with that party or *how* that authentication was performed is between that party and the user.  What's the underlying problem in this case?

Comment: If you have a case were multiple users will be using this on a shared device, or something like that - then you should instruct them to properly log out of linkedin, before letting the next person use the thing. (Some of these login providers also provide methods to log the user out from within your app, if linkedin offers something like that, you'd have to check.)

Comment: Yes. I have to login multiple accounts and to get each access tokens for further use.